# return length string in javascript when string inside in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as follows:

```
var str_array=["hello","world"]
```

How to get length of string when string are there in array?
I just want to get length of string "hello" and then "world" inside a loop.
This is what I've tried:

```
for (var i=0; i<= str_array[0].length; i++){
  alert(str_array[i].starAt(i)); 
 }
```

I get error message

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
str_array.forEach(function(e){ alert("Length = " + e.length) });
```

You could also use `map` to get the length out of each element:

```
var lengths = str_array.map(function(e){ return e.length });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var str_array = ["hello", "world"];
for (var i = 0, len = str_array.length; i < len; i++) {
  alert('Length of ' + str_array[i] + ' is ' + str_array[i].length);
}
```

Comment: Its a variable, used just for optimization purpose. I dont want length to be calculate every time loop is iterated..

Comment: can you help me to directly analyzing my code in this forum 
http://coderbyte.com/CodingArea/Editor.php?ct=Letter%20Changes&lan=JavaScript&kc=
actually i am trying to finish number 4 challenges  to make simple encryption with my own algorhytm?